# Reading int value from a SQL database

Tags: c#, database, int

please is that someone can help me avoire read the values ​​of types int the database

> int s = dr["IdSociete"]

Comment: avoire  ? is that a mistype ?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid null value conversion like this otherwise ti will give you an error

```
if(dr["IdSociete"]!=DBNull.Value)
   int s =  Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdSociete"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)**

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(dr["IdSociete"], out number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the types of the columns? If "dr" is a System.Data.DataRow, then you can access the column type of "IdSociete" by:

```
var columnType = dr.Table.Columns["IdSociete"].DataType;
```